# Speedup DROP huge MySQL replicated table

Tags: mysql, performance, replication, drop-table

I've a **huge InnoDB** table `customer_users_old` (**150G**) that it's not in use anymore in the database, it was renamed from `customer_users`.

My setup has a **Master-Slave replication** of MySQL 5.5 with `innodb_file_per_table` activated, so the table has it's own files. 
As the `DROP` command takes a lot of time, I'm afraid it can have some inpact on the prodcution database.

So I'm thinking on **disaling unique and foreign key checks for the session** as it was suggested on [DROP TABLE on a huge InnoDB table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/53515/drop-table-on-a-huge-innodb-table):

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
```

And **disabling the binary log** to drop the table *first on the master* and *then on the slave* as it was suggested on [Deleting data from a large table with replication](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/80695/deleting-data-from-a-large-table-with-replication):

```
SET sql_log_bin = 0;
```

Will this speedup the process and minimize the impact on the servers load?

Comment: I hope you had `innodb_file_per_table` was `ON` when you created it.  Else the disk space would not be released to the OS.

Comment: @RickJames it's `innodb_file_per_table` is `ON` I forgot to put it, I've updated the question to clarify that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end we realized that the process was so slow because **we did try to do the `DROP` while the `mysqldump` backup was running** and the table was **blocked** by the backup process.

After the backup process had finished the `DROP` was quite fast and **took only some minutes and did not have a big inpact on the server performance**.

Answer (score 0):

This article aptly explains why there's performance impact or [slow mysql drop table](https://www.percona.com/blog/speed-up-your-large-table-drops-in-mysql/) and walks through the possible options to improve the table drop speed.